# Barchart of Differences of Prime Numbers. - Why do multiples of six occur more frequently?

Tags: prime-numbers

[Differences between Primes - First Million Primes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyCQi.jpg)

Looks like 6,12,18,24 etc. are peaks compared to their near neighbors. Any insights why?

Click on  https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyCQi.jpg to see Bar Chart

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has been asked several times on this site. The short version is that there are 'more opportunities' for gaps of 6; of the four possible residue classes mod 6 for consecutive primes, (1, 1), (1, 5), (5, 1), and (5, 5), two of these lead to a gap that's a multiple of 6, while one leads to a gap that's 2 mod 6 and one leads to a gap that's 4 mod 6.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki In fact, you gave a nice answer at the linked duplicate.

Comment: @TravisWillse That was a big part of why it sounded familiar. :-) Thank you for chasing down the link!